# How do I write a <br/> tag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I write a `<br/>` tag in JavaScript?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var mybr = document.createElement('br');
someElement.appendChild(mybr);
```

Further reading:

- https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/traversing_the_dom/
- https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/creating_and_modifying_html/

Comment: If there is a way to do it, how could I make a `<br />` instead of `<br>` with createElement? :)

Comment: No, there is no HTML or XHTML, only the DOM.

Comment: @Quentin that sounds like it should be put on a t-shirt

Answer (score 8):

```
document.write('<br/>');
```

this should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write('<br />');
```

Or, since no Stack Overflow question on JavaScript would be complete without jQuery...

http://www.thenerdary.net/post/20965430596/beautiful-element-creation-with-jquery

Answer (score -2):

Use the operator + in the document.write(var1 + "text" + and the break tag);

Comment: You should use code formatting when writing blocks of code. Use the formatter for blocks, and 3 ticks "`" for small one liners